# Laravel5.5 is not running in PHP7.0

Tags: laravel-5

As the `Laravel 8` is not supported on PHP 7.0, I decided to go with lower version of Laravel. Because, we are not in the position of upgrading the server php version.

After reading [the requirements here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#server-requirements) we found the latest `Laravel` version that is supported in `PHP7.0` will be `Laravel5.5`.

we installed the version using composer. Below is the `Laravel` version in the server.

[image]

However, still the error shows in the nginx server as below

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.2.5".

The `composer.json` in the `laravel` root directory as below

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
}
```

Any workaround to bring the application live?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "platform" : {"php": "7.0.3"},
}
```

This fakes an environment. Maybe this helps.